# how to test a whole web function with JMeter from login until the end

Tags: json, web-services, testing, jmeter, stress-testing

I want to test my office website with JMeter. 
Now I do every step manually, I copy paste parameter and value into the http request from postman. for example , email and password to test Login menu.

Now, I want to keep the result from login test to run another step, the login data can be used in "Update Profile" menu and etc.

So, i dont have to fill the parameter in other test plan. Can someone help me please..

Thanks Before.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost you need to understand how JMeter works. I will try to walk you through briefly. A "Test Plan" is the root artifact of your JMeter project and the condition to perform the desired load test is described on a "Thread Group".

1. How do you add a thread group?
   Steps: right click "Test Plan" => "add" => "Threads (Users)" => "Thread Group".
2. Add a Simple Controller to encapsulate the scope of this test.
   Steps: right click "Thread Group" => "add" => "Logic Controller" => "Simple Controller"

After having this, it is very important that you understand what is a sampler element? so, a sampler element tells JMeter to send requests to a server and wait for a response.

In your case i will assume you need to send a HTTP request to a page or probably a Restful webservice, for both cases follow this step:

3. How to add a HTTP Request sampler? 
   Steps: right click your "Simple Controller" => "Sampler" => "HTTP Request".

In this sampler is where you specify the protocol, endpoint, the body of the request and the type of request (post,get,etc.)  (In your case the endpoint will be the login url, suit yourself preparing the payload (body))

1. How do I use the session for further requests after login? just add a HTTP Cookie Manager.

Steps: right click the "Simple Controller"=> "add" => "Config Element" => "HTTP Cookie Manager"

NOTE: MAKE SURE THIS IS THE FIRST ELEMENT IN YOUR "Simple Controller".

Let me know if this answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter provides [built-in proxy server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) so you will be able to **record** your actions instead of copying and pasting them.

1. Check out [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](http://Apache%20JMeter%20HTTP(S)%20Test%20Script%20Recorder) guide for end-to-end information on how to configure JMeter and browser for recording
2. You can quickly get "good" JMeter configuration using "Templates" feature, from the main menu: File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create. See [Create Test Plan from Template](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#template) chapter for more information

---

As an alternative you can use 3rd party Proxy Recorder which not only simplifies the process of recording, it produces so called SmartJMX - a recorded JMeter test with applied dynamic extractors so you won't have to do the correlation manually.

See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for detailed information.